# My cursor is at the beginning of my bash prompt. Any ideas why?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm using a slightly modified version of Gary Bernhardt's (destroyallsoftware.com) .bashrc with homebrew bash 3.2.51.

```
    #  . ~/bin/bash_colors.sh
    . ~/bin/colorize.sh

[... snipped ...]

    # Git prompt components
    function minutes_since_last_commit {
        now=`date +%s`
        last_commit=`git log --pretty=format:'%at' -1`
        seconds_since_last_commit=$((now-last_commit))
        minutes_since_last_commit=$((seconds_since_last_commit/60))
        echo $minutes_since_last_commit
    }
    grb_git_prompt() {
        local g="$(__gitdir)"
        if [ -n "$g" ]; then
            local MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT=`minutes_since_last_commit`
            if [ "$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT" -gt 30 ]; then
                local COLOR=${txtred}
            elif [ "$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT" -gt 10 ]; then
                local COLOR=${txtylw}
            else
                local COLOR=${txtgrn}
            fi
            local SINCE_LAST_COMMIT="${COLOR}$(minutes_since_last_commit)${reset}"
            # The __git_ps1 function inserts the current git branch where %s is
            # *** richard -- added purple to branch name


             local GIT_PROMPT=`__git_ps1 "[\033${txtgrn}%s\033${reset}|\033${SINCE_LAST_COMMIT}]"`
            echo ${GIT_PROMPT}
        fi
    }
    PS1="\[${txtblu}\u\[${txtmag}@\h\[${reset}:\[\W\]\[\$(grb_git_prompt)\$ "

[... snipped ...]
```

For some reason, my prompt does this:

[image]

Until I do:

```
$ bash
```

at which point it does this:

[image]

This exact same .bashrc and associated scripts work perfectly on my arch box.

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\u\[@\h\[:\[\W\]\[$(grb_git_prompt)$
```

The same thing happens in both Terminal.app and iTerm2. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could comment pieces of the .bashrc file to find the culprit. Could you also post the contents of the files that are being sourced from your .bashrc?

Comment: As @glennjackman spotted in his answer, you make a second unnecessary call to `minutes_since_last_commit` which can be replaced by the contents of variable `$MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT`. This should halve the response time of your bash prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly the contents of your colour variables, I think you need to change this

```
PS1="\[${txtblu}\u\[${txtmag}@\h\[${reset}:\[\W\]\[\$(grb_git_prompt)\$ "
```

to this

```
PS1="\[\033${txtblu}\]\u\[\033${txtmag}\]@\h\[\033${reset}\]:\W\$(grb_git_prompt)\$ "
```

And change this

```
local SINCE_LAST_COMMIT="${COLOR}$(minutes_since_last_commit)${reset}"
local GIT_PROMPT=`__git_ps1 "[\033${txtgrn}%s\033${reset}|\033${SINCE_LAST_COMMIT}]"`
echo ${GIT_PROMPT}
```

to

```
local SINCE_LAST_COMMIT="\[\033${COLOR}\]${MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT}\[\033${reset}\]"
echo "$(__git_ps1 "\[\033${txtgrn}\]%s\[\033${reset}\]|${SINCE_LAST_COMMIT}")"
```

The colour codes all have to be individually surrounded by `\[...\]`

Comment: Note that @glenn jackman changed `$(minutes_since_last_commit)` to `${MINUTES_SINCE_LAST_COMMIT}` in his answer. This is a good thing. It should improve the prompt response time.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that your colour definitions (which I can't see in your question) already have the surrounding `\[` and `\]` characters. I.e. your yellow is something like this:

```
txtylw="\[\033[0;37m\]"
```

And this is what's causing the confusion and the problem.

The PS1 prompt needs those surrounding characters, but the colours returned by your `grb_git_prompt()` function **must not**, because this function gets called every time you press `Enter` and it's output will get inserted *literally* into your prompt.

Put these at the top of your `grb_git_prompt()` function to see if I'm right:

```
local txtred="\033[0;31m"
local txtylw="\033[0;37m"
local txtgrn="\033[0;32m"
local reset="\033[0m"
```

P.S. I'm not sure if my actual colour numbers are correct.